# Can an iOS app sell user created content with In-App Purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, revenuecat

I've been trying to figure out how to sell user-created content in an iOS app using StoreKit, but I'm having trouble finding anything on this in the documentation.

The app I'd like to develop would essentially allow users to create blog posts, and then sell them in a marketplace section within the app. Each post would be considered a non-consumable, and the creator would set the price. FWIW I already have the frontend and backend completed for everything except for In-App Purchases, and I plan on using RevenueCat for most of that.

1. Is this type of setup possible with Apple In-App Purchases, or do all products need to be specified by the app developer in App Store Connect?
2. Is it possible that this use case qualifies for bypassing the In-App Purchase ecosystem entirely, and instead we can use something like Stripe?

Comment: The typical solution for this kind of issue is for you to sell "credits" via IAP these credits can be redeemed by users for the content. The content creators can set the number of credits to purchase their content.  You then create consumable IAPs for bundles of credits. I don't think this use case qualifies for bypassing IAP.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your answer; this is the conclusion I've come to as well. Another feature we want to add, which I didn't mention, is allowing users to subscribe to creators for a fee to get access to all their blog posts. Similarly to the above question, it seems like all subscription products need to be declared in App Store Connect ahead of time. Could a "credits" based approach be used for allowing a user to have infinite subscriptions to other users?

Comment: Sure. It's up to you what your app delivers. If the subscription is for a limited time, however, then you are going to have to manage the expiration of the subscription